# TensorFlow exception: module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.math' has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run version 1.8 of TensorFlow on Python 3.

I am getting the following exception:

```
import tensorflow as tf

Matrix_one = tf.constant([[2,3],[3,4]])

with tf.Session() as session:

    print(session.run(tf.math.log(Matrix_one)))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.api.generator.api.math' has no attribute 'log'
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results. Check the version using `print (tf.__version__)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf

Matrix_one = tf.constant([[2,3],[3,4]],dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as session:

    print(session.run(tf.log(Matrix_one)))
```

The result is as follows:
[[0.6931472 1.0986123]
 [1.0986123 1.3862944]]

```
    tf.log(
        x,
        name=None
    )
The parameter x must be one of the following types:

bfloat16, half, float32, float64, complex64, complex128
```

At version 1.11 and above, the tf.math.log function is available because tensorflow moves the base arithmetic operator into tf.math.